# Webscraping automation How to simulate click of HREF link where no link TAG is there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, automation, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape/automate a certain website but struggling to know where to start - I know you can point me in the right direction here - in my example - selecting a horse odds.

If you follow this link http://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing and then click on any of the races, I want to be able to automate on a race meeting - the user clicking of the odds of one of the horses at one of the bookmakers but there is no anchor or HREF tags or any link for me to tap into programmatically.

Here is an example of what inspector throws up:

```html
<td class="bc bs o" data-odig="5.5" data-o="9/2" data-hcap="">5.5</td>
```

I want to be able to simulate the user clicking on that 5.5 in the TD.

Many thanks.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

If you can click on this  and it actually fires an event, then there is javascript listening to that event. You can get the Javascript to execute with JQuery:

```
$("td [data-odig='5.5']").click();
```

(Obviously the selector should be updated for whichever element you want to click.)

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/click/

So you need to be able to run your own arbitrary JavaScript in the page, and then you can accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks @Padge - however there is no 'apparent' unique cell ID (see HTML snippet below) - somehow I think I need to run it through some kind of traffic analyser upon execution to be able to see how individual cells are identified - any ideas?


       <td class="bc bs oi b" data-odig="8" data-o="7" data-hcap="">8</td>
      <td class="bc bs oi b" data-odig="8" data-o="7" data-hcap="">8</td>
      <td class="bc bs oi b" data-odig="6" data-o="5" data-hcap="">6</td>

Comment: Since the cells have no apparent way to contain unique identifiers, how would cells with the same value inside the <td> element be identified as different? Can you find an instance of this?

Comment: After running it through the debugger the first line of the event listener seems to be suggesting x,y coordinates see screenshot image [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Sf9qx1nwCybnZEaTB6QUdWVEk)

Comment: Could this be the ID, possibly, for the clicked cell? [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Sf9qx1nwCyV1lDWDlVODZhbFU/view?usp=sharing) It does vary in sympathy with the selected cell clicked.